# R (data.table) Keep rows in DT1 with values of a given variable not present in DT2 for given matched values of other variables

Tags: r, list, merge, data.table

I have two data.tables. The first one has information of all `colleague ids` of a given individual `id` at a given `month`. The data is presented in long format (i.e., if an individual has 3 colleagues at a given month, we have 3 rows for that same individual-month).

The second dataset informs the `list` of all colleagues of a given individual for a given month. There is only a single row for each id-month.

All id-month contained in the first dataset can be found in this second dataset. However, not all colleague ids informed in the first dataset can be found within the list of colleagues for the respective id-month. I would like to keep the rows of the first dataset which inform ids not included in the list of colleagues for a given id-month.

Below is a simple example.

```
library(data.table)

pairs <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
  colleague_id = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 2, 4, 1, 11, 12)
)

list_colleagues <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  month = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
  colleague_ids = list(c(2, 4, 5), c(2, 4), c(1,10), 12)
)
```

The code below works fine. However, I would like to make it more efficient. Is there a way to code this in a way that I don't have to attach the list of colleagues to the first dataset as a prior step to then check if the colleague ids is in that list.

```
keep_excluded <- list_colleagues[pairs, on=.(id, month)]

keep_excluded <- keep_excluded[, 
                               keep := !colleague_id %in% colleague_ids[[1]], 1:nrow(keep_excluded)][
  keep==TRUE][, 
              keep:=NULL][, 
                          colleague_ids:=NULL]
```

Output

```
   id month colleague_id
1:  1     1            3
2:  1     1           10
3:  2     1           11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert to `list_colleagues` to a friendlier format then perform anti-join:

```r
lc2 <- list_colleagues[, .(colleague_id = unlist(colleague_ids)), by = .(id, month)]

pairs[!lc2, on = names(pairs)]

#       id month colleague_id
#    <num> <num>        <num>
# 1:     1     1            3
# 2:     1     1           10
# 3:     2     1           11
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `.EACHI` on the join step itself

```
library(data.table)
setnames(list_colleagues[pairs, lapply(colleague_ids, \(x) 
   colleague_id[!colleague_id %in% x]), on = .(id, month), 
     by = .EACHI], 'V1', 'colleague_id')[]
```

-output

```
     id month colleague_id
   <num> <num>        <num>
1:     1     1            3
2:     1     1           10
3:     2     1           11
```

---

Or may also do

```
list_colleagues[pairs, .(colleague_id = setdiff(colleague_id, 
      unlist(colleague_ids))), on = .(id, month), by = .EACHI]
      id month colleague_id
   <num> <num>        <num>
1:     1     1            3
2:     1     1           10
3:     2     1           11
```

NOTE: Both solution does in a single join